# JavaScript that must be placed outside a function

Tags: java, javascript, merge, diff

We have a tool that generates the source code (for C#, Java, IOS, etc.) from a given model. The code is manually edited for any feature that is missing by the code generator. Whenever any changes made to the model and needs to generate the source code out of it, the manual changes that performed on the previous version are lost.

In order to minimize the loss, the user edited code blocks (methods, classes, properties, etc.) are marked with a custom attribute (say `CUSTCODE`). While generating the source for the new version, if a path for previous version is mentioned (by user), system will compare the two source codes and merge the contents as follows (previous version is considered as the base in this case):

1. Remove any code blocks that are available in previous version and not available in new version, which are not marked as CUSTCODE.
2. Replace any code blocks that are available in both the versions, and not marked as CUSTCODE with latest version code.
3. Add the missing code blocks from the latest code.

For this, we are using `Microsoft Roslyn` and is working as expected for C# (of course additional checks like usings are performed)

[Note: I can use Java / C# for the merger app. The system is going to invoke any app by passing params. The same is achieved using `ASTRewriter` for Java]

Now the challenge is for the JS and HTML. Currently We are focusing at JS.
We have checked several AST JavaScript parsers like Rhino, IronJS, astify etc. But I am blocked at some point in using them.

So I want to build a custom merger. Since JavaScript is so dynamic, we are (going to) setting up the guidelines for JS code.

1. Enclose all the code within a named function, which acts as unique identifier to match and merge.
2. Add a comment with "CUSTCODE" on top of the method when system need to keep the function intact while merge.

Our intention is to follow the following approach:

1. Move the anonymous functions found in jQuery into named functions and call them in jQuery
2. Name any anonymous function like var v = function()...
3. Wrap all jQueries and standalone pieces of code into named self executable functions while keeping the order intact.
4. Move all global variables to top of the JS file. (Do not enclose in any function)

The merging process works as follows:

1. Capture all strings (single quote, double quote), comments (inline, block) and replace with some unique identifiers. (Except the ones tagged with "CUSTCODE"
2. Capture the function body (based on the count of '{' and '}') and replace with unique identifier. Read the previous line, mark the method if it is "CUSTCODE"
3. Compare and replace the captured function bodies with latest version content appropriately.
4. Restore all captures to generate the final output.

I am wondering if anything else I need to consider.

Comment: Why not use git/svn to compare files? You'll get in a lot of problems with the way you described.

Comment: There are tons of compare/merge tools available, why do you want to write your own?

Comment: Why are you handling jQuery specially?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use any such tools. The only way is to write a java/.net app to process the files. The code is originally generated by a tool based on some design, further maintained by users. The newfile may be the one generated by the tool again.

Comment: If it has to be written in Java, but Git is basically what you need, would [JavaGit](http://javagit.sourceforge.net/) be an acceptable tool? Looks like the website is a few years out of date, unfortunately (check the News page).

Comment: Not all the codes placed into repository. Indeed the code is maintained by end users. We have no control over what they would use. The tool would take two paths and merge.

Comment: @KrishnaSarma: Who _has_ control over what is used by whom ? given the scenario you've outlined (in particular matching functions by name only while end users appear to operate rather oblivious to each other), who would want to merge in the first place? no offense intended, but that sounds like a maintenance nightmare in the making.

Comment: I have edited the question with a detailed use case.